# What good are free groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, free-groups

In [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf), one learns two definitions of **free groups** associating with sets.

> 1. Let $A$ be a set, the free group of $A$, $F(A)$ is the **initial object** in the category $\mathcal{C}$, where \begin{equation}
>    \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})=\{A\xrightarrow{g}G\},
>    \end{equation}where the codomain $G$ are groups, and \begin{equation}
>    \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{C})=\{\text{Commutative Diagrams } A\xrightarrow{g_1}G_1\xrightarrow{\phi}G_2\xleftarrow{g_2}A\} 
>    \end{equation} where $\phi$ are group homomorphisms.
> 2. Also $F(A)$ has the concrete construction with elements being non-redundant words with alphabet $A$, and the group multiplication being juxtaposition and reduction.

But what good are free groups? Why are they useful? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) says they are useful in topology, but does not explain why explicity.

Can someone give some examples that an undergraduate can understand? I am asking about examples that can show the usefulness of this abstract construction. So I guess the identification of $\mathbb{Z}=F({a})$ does not really count.

Comment: What good is a free dinner?  Really, do you have to ask?

Comment: Well, I'm personally a big fan of the integers--a.k.a. the free group with one generator.

Comment: Have you ever stopped to think what it means to give a presentation of a group by generators and relations? You'll find that you will need the concept of free group in order to make sense of this rigorously.

Comment: @ZhenLin That is a good point! But this is actually only a *technicality*. Is there some good examples that we use free groups to solve problems?

Comment: @HuiYu, Just knowing what a free group wont solve any complicated problems. It's just a natural concept that arises in group theory.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but it may be of interest: http://www.springerlink.com/content/ll61220g664q4475/

Comment: Also, how much topology do you know? In particular, do you know how to find the fundamental group of the wedge of circles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually, for algebraic structures,

> Any structure is a *quotient* of a free such structure.

If we are given abstractly operation symbols $\mu,\nu,+,\cdot,...$, and a positive number as the *arity* of the operation (e.g. '$+$' is a binary symbol), then one can define *formal* terms, built up by pregiven variables (associated to the elements of the given set $A$) and these operation symbols. Basically these terms are just 'strings' like $\mu(a+b,c\cdot d, e)$ if $\mu$ is ternary operation symbol.

The main thing is, that the set of terms naturally admits a structure of the given type, the operation symbols act just formally. And this is the *free algebra* of the given type.

If, in addition, some *rules* are present (axioms for the given structures, like associativity for groups) , then these rules should also be applied to the set of the terms, considering a *quotient* of it, e.g. where the strings
$(a\cdot b)\cdot c$  and  $a\cdot (b\cdot c)$ are *identified* with each other. (Hence, if associativity of the operation is imposed, it is enough to consider the finite sequences like $(a,b,c,a,a,c)$.)

So, free groups, in this sense, are *so general*, that every group is 'contained' (as a quotient) of them. On the other hand, every group can be embedded to a *symmetric group*. So, symmetric groups have similar important role (at least, in this view).

In topology, for example, the fundamental group of $n$ circles glued together at one point is the free group on $n$ generators.

Free groups also may provide easy counterexamples of statements like '*identities $P,Q$ on groups imply identity $R$*'. If this is not true, then the quotient 'by $P$ and $Q$' of a suitable free group must be a counterexample.

Answer (score 15):

As an example of whar @Berci noted; we know that:

> Every group $G$ is a quotient of a free group.

Theorem above let us to identified $G$ with $\frac{F}{R}$ where in $F$ is a free group and $R$ is a normal subgroup of it. Now if we denote $X$ as a base for $F$ and $\delta$ as a family of words (like a sequence of alphabets above), then $X$ is known as the *generators* of $G$ and $\delta$ as its *relations*. Here, we propose a new symbol as $G=\langle X|R \rangle$ and we call it a *presentation* of $G$. As I have worked some problems in this kind of structures, without knowing a presentation of a group some beautiful facts about that group may be neglected. How can we introduce $A_4$ easier. How can we work with $S_3$ when a student forget its certain permutations? The Free groups and their great theorems help us to work with such these groups easier. Indeed $A_4=\langle a,b|a^2=b^3=(ab)^3=1\rangle$ and $S_3=\langle a,b|a^2=b^3=(ab)^2=1\rangle$. It is easy to memorize, at least for me.

Comment: And we know, for free, that the structure presented is a group, and don't need to check so!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat application which I originally learned from [a paper of Bergman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1391): given a group $G$ and letting $F_k$ be the free group on $k$ elements, we can think of $G*F_k$ as being $G$ augmented with $k$ "generic" elements (and this can be generalized to other categories of algebraic structutres with the free product being replaced by coproduct). Given some additional structure on $G$ which "lifts along" homomorphisms out of $G$, we can use this to get nontrivial information. For example, the Bergman paper linked above shows that for an automorphism $\alpha$ of a group $G$, the following are equivalent:

- There is an assignment $Hom(G,-)\rightarrow Aut(-):f\mapsto \beta_f$ such that $\beta_{f_2}h=h\beta_{f_1}$ for any $h: H_1\rightarrow H_2$, $f_1: G\rightarrow H_1$, $f_2: G\rightarrow H_2$ with $hf_1=f_2$.
- $\alpha$ is an inner automorphism of $G$, that is, for some $g\in G$ we have $\alpha:x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$.

It actually says more than this, the issue being that multiple $\beta_-$s may correspond (= evaluate at $\mathit{id}$) to the same $\alpha$. It turns out that the $\beta_-$s with the above properties are in really nice correspondence with the elements of $G$ themselves: a given $\beta_-$ must be of the form $f\mapsto (x\mapsto f(g)xf(g)^{-1})$ for some $g\in G$.