# Inductive proof of associativity of free groups

Tags: group-theory, induction, free-groups, associativity

I'm really struggling with the inductive proof of the associativity of free groups, given about halfway down page 6 of [this pdf](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/aisiit.pdf).

The bit I'm not getting is this:

> Suppose now that bc involves a cancellation; so c = b<sup>-1</sup>v starts with b<sup>-1</sup>. Therefore, (ab)c = wc = w(b<sup>-1</sup>v) while a(bc) = a(v) = (wb<sup>-1</sup>)v. **Since l(w) + l(v) < l(a) + l(c), the last two terms are equal by induction hypothesis.** Hence, the associativity holds when l(b) = 1.

I don't understand what $l(a) + l(c)$ has to do with anything, and why the fact that $l(w) + l(v) < l(a) + l(c)$ means that "the last two terms are equal". I am familiar with proof by induction, but I don't get how it works in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks as though the proof is by induction on $l(a)+l(c)$. The base case is when $l(a)=l(c)=0$, and the claim is trivial. Since $l(w)+l(v)<l(a)+l(c)$, we can assume by induction that the result is true when $a,b,c$ are replaced by $w,b^{-1},v$. Hence $w(b^{-1}v)=(wb^{-1})v$.

Comment: There are ways to construct free groups without the fuzz of equivalence classes, reduced words, struggle with associativity, etc. If you are interested then have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/855321/75923).

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh I think I get it now -- I wasn't familiar with strong induction as opposed to weak induction. We know associativity holds for the base case $l(a) + l(c) = 0$, and _**if**_ we assume that it holds for $l(w) + l(v) < l(a) + l(c)$ _**then**_ it follows that it also holds for $l(a) + l(c).$ Therefore, it holds for all $l(a) + l(c)$.