# Properties unique to free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I was just working on a problem for my Algebra class about proving that a group was free. I was able to figure that out, but it got me wondering: are there any properties that are unique to free groups that are useful in proving that a group is free? Or a few properties that are only all satisfied in a free group?

That may have been a little vague, and I am sorry about that. I know that this kind of vagueness is not desirable on MSE, but I am really just curious about this :)

EDIT: I am interested in finitely generated free groups

Comment: Which definition of a free group are you using?

Comment: @Shaun I am talking about non-abelian free groups

Comment: Still, free groups have more than one definition. They are, of course, equivalent, but which one you use would determine what unique properties - properties in alternative definitions - they have.

Comment: @Shaun I am considering $F_n = \langle a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \rangle$ where there are no relations between the generators.

Comment: So, do they have to be finitely generated?

Comment: @Shaun Yes, I am interested in finitely generated free groups. I will update the question!

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/855321/104041)

Comment: @Shaun this is probably completely wrong, but I heard once that Hopfian, imperfect, and finitely generated implies free. Is this true?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of in that regard is that every finitely generated free group is Hopfian. This is **Proposition 3.5** of Lyndon & Schupp.

Comment: @Shaun not super related, but is it known exactly which families of groups are Hopfian?

Comment: I don't know (yet), @Anonymous. I'll look into it.

Comment: "Hopfian, imperfect, and finitely generated implies free" is very much false. For instance, finite rank abelian groups, fundamental groups of surfaces of genus $\ge 1$, etc, all share these properties.