# Good introduction to free groups and free products

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, free-groups, free-product

In my undergraduate research project, I am going to study a paper on free products in division rings. To do this, however, I, of course, need to learn about free groups and free products.

Right now, the only reference I have is Rotman's "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups". Is this a good reference? Or is there a better book to get the intuition and the main theorems behind free groups?

Please have in mind that I am self-studying and that, being an undergrad, if it is possible to avoid too much Category Theory, it would be best.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the risk of evangelizing: I understand wanting to avoid "too much" category theory, but a little bit of category theory (namely universal properties and adjoint functors) can _really_ grease the wheels when it comes to understanding free groups and free products.

Comment: If I may add a suggestion to Shaun's excellent one: Stillwell's "Classical Topology and Combinatorial Group Theory" is characteristically well written. The group theory in that book definitely exists in service to the topology, but it does a great job presenting the basics and providing some context for a lot of these constructions (which are, in my mind at least, inherently geometric).

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Do you have any book recommendations for an introduction to Category Theory?

Comment: There's a few good ones, and everyone does things in a slightly different order. I recommend skimming the first chapter of Awodey's book and Leinster's book (which has the benefit of being [free](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375)) and seeing whose style you like more. Also, the first chapter of Aluffi's Algebra book (and, while you're there, Chapter II.5 on free groups) is a great practical introduction.

Answer (score 4):

Try Magnus *et al.*'s, *"Combinatorial Group Theory: Presentations of Groups in Terms of Generators and Relations"*. It's quite a comprehensive treatment of free groups and free products, alongside other concepts.

The following question of mine might be of interest too.

[Different ways of constructing the free group over a set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/855321/104041)

Comment: +1 This is an excellent, classical text which has stood the test of time. The exercises are, to quote my supervisor, "a work of art".